# Restarting web server: apache2 failed!

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to restart apache and it's saying

Restarting web server: apache2 failed!

anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: If you bring me a dead cat all I can tell you is that it's dead, and it was a cat... (We'll need a lot more information to help you -- like perhaps something out of the Apache error logs that explains why it failed to start. :-)

Comment: Check your error log, used to be in /var/log/apache/

Comment: running debian os

Comment: And now, give us your error log.

Comment: it's not logging any errors for the apache2 reboot

Comment: reinstalled apache moved the files back and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your config file. You didn't say which OS you are on, but Apache can validate it's own config:

```
httpd -t
```

Call your platform's Apache binary with -t at the end to validate the config.

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of things to make sure Apache really isn't running. First, check

```
ps axf |grep [a]pache
```

This will tell you if apache is running. If a result pops up, kill that process and try starting Apache again.

Second, make sure nothing is listening on port 80 (although this would log an error, but hey).

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 80
```

Again, if this shows a process, kill it and try Apache again.

As an aside, can you check your Apache configuration and let me know what the value for the LogLevel directive is? You can try setting this to debug and trying the restart again.